# How do I run WSL 'docker compose' command in Intellij Idea?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, intellij-idea, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL with Ubuntu and docker-compose plugin installed on Windows 10. Now, I can run `docker compose` command (v2) from my PowerShell or Idea's terminal like this: `wsl docker compose up`. And everything works fine. But Intellij Idea does not work properly for me when I'm trying to run **docker-compose Configuration**, instead, I'm getting the error:
`wsl --env-file -f C:\Users\myName\IdeaProjects\microservices\music-app\docker-compose.yml -p music-app up /bin/bash: line 1: /: Is a directory 'docker-compose' process finished with exit code 126`:

[image]

The question also is - why after `wsl` there is no `docker compose` command?
Containers and Images run well using Idea.
What should I check? What have I missed?

I have changed Docker config like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Despite the red highlighting, I manually set the following docker path and everything now works:
[image]